# Imessaging when travelling and not using cellular

Tags: messages

I would like to know whether iMessages will revert to text messages when I travel overseas and have my cellular set to "off when roaming". I normally use SMS or MMS to keep in touch when travelling.

Comment: "Blue" messages will work, "green" will not.

Answer (score 1):

Providing you have `Settings > Messages > Send as SMS` toggled on and `Settings > Mobile Data > Mobile Data Options > Data Roaming` toggled off then yes, messages sent from the Messages app will go as SMS.